# Why doesn't specialization of std::hash() need to be injected into std namespace in this particular case?

Tags: c++, template-specialization, specialization

Consider

```
using namespace std;

template <typename S, typename T> struct hash<pair<S, T>>
{
    inline size_t operator()(const pair<S, T> &v) const
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

In this case both GCC and Clang compile it fine with no warnings. This however seems to contradict what I've read online that defining your own hash function to be used with the standard library's unordered types requires you to place the definition in the std namespace.

Interestingly, specializing only for `pair<int, int>`:

```
template <> struct hash<pair<int, int>>
{
    size_t operator()(const pair<int, int> &v) const
    {
        size_t seed = 0;
        return seed;
    }
};
```

leads to an error as we expect.

However, why does the first not lead to any compiler warnings despite the fact that we are not placing it in the std namespace?

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug

Comment: OT: Don't inject your hash function into the `std` namespace.  Use the `Hash` template argument of the corresponding containers (e.g. [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)).

Comment: The rules for this have changed from version to version of C++. I'm working on an answer, but it will take a bit more research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to [Core Language Issue 727](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#727) (deleted text is deleted after the resolution, italic text is newly added after the resolution, and bold text is emphasized by me):

> An explicit specialization  <del>shall be declared in a namespace enclosing the specialized template. **An explicit specialization whose declarator-id or class-head-name is not qualified shall be declared in the nearest enclosing namespace of the template**, or, if the namespace is inline (10.3.1 [namespace.def]), any namespace from its enclosing namespace set. Such a declaration may also be a definition</del>  *may be declared in any scope in which the corresponding primary template may be defined (10.3.1.2 [namespace.memdef], 12.2 [class.mem], 17.6.2 [temp.mem])*.

Note the bold text, the nearest enclosing namespace of `std::hash` is `std`, and your explicit specialization is not declared in `std`, so it is ill-formed before the resolution. Partial specialization does not has this constraint, so your first example is well-formed even before the resolution.

Now both your examples should be well-formed after the resolution. You can see both Clang and MSVC [accept the code](https://godbolt.org/g/ztNKdL) (note an older version of Clang [rejects it](https://godbolt.org/g/cAaSDr)). For GCC, this is already a [reported bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85282).

Answer (score 0):

As it is written here http://umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/NamespaceGuide.pdf

> "You are directing the compiler to make all of the names in the std namespace part of the global namespace, and thus they can be
>   referred to without qualification in the rest of your source code file. They will now collide with any names that your own code uses.
>   This takes effect only for the current compilation unit (the file that is being compiled)."

The first one is good example, because you import all `std` content (like `hash` template) to your global namespace, so you can write its specialization without errors. In second case it doesn't work, because of leak of any `hash` template to be specialized.